# What user experience principles do website developers use to determine how to create a homepage in general?

Tags: homepage

On the Facebook homepage, I have usually seen a top post followed by an ad followed by a throwback post and so on.

On the Google homepage also I see something similar, a top article followed by an ad followed by a throwback article as "In Case You Missed It".

I see similar types of lists in the homepages of other websites also.

My question here is: What are the UX principles the developers use to determine how to create a homepage in general?

Comment: Maybe it's me but I don't understand the question. Are you designing a page with a list of articles or posts?

Comment: @bloodyKnuckles I am not designing a page. I am asking a general question about a website homepage.

Comment: Are you asking how to design a page that is primarily composed of a list? This being a UX site, are you asking for the UX principles that apply to presenting lists? You mention posts (having a chronological characteristic) and articles (being search topic related). Are there other types of lists you have in mind, or is your question limited to these two types?

Comment: @bloodyKnuckles I am asking for the UX principles that apply to presenting lists. The question refers to all types of lists.

Comment: Please update your question with your comment so people don't need to read the comments to better understand your request.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Many large websites are constantly testing to see what works best. A lot of these decisions are based on their internal research. The homepage is very important real estate on a website. Including ads there can create a lot of impressions, but if you put too many ads then it takes away from the original purpose of the page and gets annoying. They probably found through their testing that sandwiching the ad between two interesting things is best for the user experience.

I would recommend Steve Krug's book "Don't Make Me Think" it describes websites from a usability perspective. It's a very easy read. In the book he discusses how to best design a website (homepage included) to get the most out of it.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 2):

> What are the...UX principles that apply to presenting...all types of lists.

Consider the nature of the list. How are the list items related to each other?

- Chronological
- Topical
- Linear vs. Hierarchical

Analyze the content to identify the various ways the list items are best sorted and filtered.

**Sort**: *Date, Relevance, Alphabetic...* Sorting reorders the list items.

**Filter**: *Source, Descriptive characteristics, Ranges...* Filtering reduces the quantity of list items.

Initially sort the list by the highest priority order, such as chronological, or relevance. Typically lists are not filtered by default, unless data analysis and/or user testing demonstrates improved user experience if a default filter is applied, such as a checking account balance register filtered by the current month.

Group sort controls and filter controls together and place according to priority, making the most often used sorts and filters the easiest to locate and use.

Determine the desired user responses. Emphasize the desired action, such as clicking an article or post title, or selecting an item for inclusion in a bulk action.

Identify additional requirements, such as advertising. How can the additional purposes be incorporated into or along with the list in a meaningful way that clearly distinguishes the list results from the associated purpose, and doesn't confuse, annoy, or interfere with the page's primary purpose.